# SignalR inside an iframe not receiving

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, iframe

My web application that utilizes signalR sent from an API hub works well on all browsers. Now, when I try to add the link of my web application inside an iframe within a basic html page, my web application does not execute my connection methods.

Here a snippet of my code in my web application:

```
$.connection.hub.url = 'myUrl';
$.connection.hub.logging = true;
var varHub= $.connection.MyHub;
$.connection.hub.start()
    .done(function () { console.log("Signal R connected"); //this is being executed })
    .fail(function () { console.log("Could not Connect to signal R hub!"); });

$.connection.hub.disconnected(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $.connection.hub.start();
    }, 5000); // Re-start connection after 5 seconds
});

//Methods to be called by the server for signal R connections
varHub.client.start= function () {
    //this is not being called
    //do something
};
```

As I have said I have no problems when I directly access it via url. The issue only happens when I try to insert the url in an iframe.

Here's how I do it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11">
    </head>
    <body width="1280" height="736" style="margin:0;padding:0;overflow:hidden;border:0px;background:#000000;">
        <iframe 
            src="http://myUrl/Home/Index?Id=someId" style="width:1280px;height:720px;margin:0;paddin:0;overflow:hidden;border:0px;"/>
            scrolling="no"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Note: My target browser is IE 11.**

Any ideas will be a great help! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who will might encounter this in the future, this parameter fixed my issue.

Source: [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr)

> Negotiating a transport takes a certain amount of time and client/server resources. If the client capabilities are known, then a transport can be specified when the client connection is started. The following code snippet demonstrates starting a connection using the Ajax Long Polling transport, as would be used if it was known that the client did not support any other protocol:

```
$.connection.hub.start({ transport: 'longPolling' })
```